# How to combine 2 values into one with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I am submitting a form element named "CCExp" it is made up of two select boxes #Month and #Year. I need to combine #Month and #Year so it submits as MM/YYYY.

```
$("#CCExp").val($("#Month") + '/' + $("#Year"));
```

Is this close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close.  I think this should do it:

```
$('#CCExp').val($('#Month').val() + '/' + $('#Year').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL date insert, this is a way to create the date type:

```
var date = $('#year').val() + '-' + $('#month').val() + '-' + $('#day').val();
```

Just came up with it as a newbee with the insight from the guys above.