# Extract the value from input dynamically with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Good morning
I have the next html

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="formula"> 
           <label for="from">Mathematical</label>
           <input id="texto" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="variables"></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

and this JQuery code

```
$.grep(arrayVariables, function(el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, arrayPintar) == -1) difference.push(el);
              console.log("2. antes del pop");
                arrayPintar.push(el);

            console.log("difference  " +difference);
             var identificador= difference.pop();


                    console.log("IDENTIFICADOR  "  +identificador);
                    console.log("3. despues del pop");
              if (identificador!=null){
                  $("#container div#variables").append("<div id='"+identificador+"'>\n\
                                                       <label for=\"var\">'"+identificador+"':</label> <label for=\"from\">From:</label>    \n\
                                                      <input type=\"number\" name=\"From\"> \n\
                                                      \n\
                                                       <label for=\"To\">To:</label>  \n\
                                                       <input type=\"number\" name=\"To\"> \n\
                                                       \n\  <label for=\"Step\">Step:</label> \n\
                                                         <input type=\"number\" name=\"Step\"></div>");
                 }
            });//FIN GREP /////////
```

And I need the value of all my input. How can I get it?

Something like this?

```
$('div#container div#variables div#+identificador+  input[name="Step"]').val ()
```

Comment: You want to get all the values? How? In an array, in an object (if an object what keys/properties do you need or want to use?)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **.each()** loop to get all input values :

For I.E.

```
$('input[name="Step"]').each(function(){
alert($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Thank u to every one for your answers : ))

Answer (score 0):

You can combine values like this: `$('#texto').val()+$('#othertext').val();`

see more:

[How to combine 2 values into one with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243347/how-to-combine-2-values-into-one-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

for all inputs you can try

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: to get values you can use alert($(this).val());

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to add all the values of input and put it into an array. If yes, then the bellow code will word.

```
var inputArray=[];
$('input').each(function(){
inputArray.push($(this).val());
});
```